# How do I interpret the output of a neurolab simulation?

Tags: python, neural-network, data-mining

I am using neurolab to simulate a neural network to classify a dataset into a binary classification.

I have the data in a dataframe.I am creating a neural network with one input value and one output value and 10 hidden nodes.

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("training.csv")
target = df_train['outputcol'] # already encoded into 0's and 1's
inp = df_train.INPUT_AMT.values.reshape(df_train.INPUT_AMT.count(),1)
output = target.reshape(len(target),1) #reshaping into a matrix
```

Then I create a model, min_input and max_input are calculated :

```
net = nl.net.newff([[min_input,max_imput]], [10,1]) 
error = net.train(inp,output)
out = net.sim(inp)
```

This is the contents of the variable `out`:

```
array([[ 0.46434608],
   [ 0.47084458],
   [ 0.46583954],
   ..., 
   [ 0.46898838],
   [ 0.22519667],
   [ 0.46541441]])
```

How is this supposed to be interpreted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on our Piazza page (UC Berkeley, INFO290t) seems correct:

> I believe you're supposed to round the output to zero or one and then compare the rounded results with your target to determine the accuracy.
>
> "If the output of your classifier is a continuous value between 0 and 1, such as with a neural network with sigmoid output node, then you can round the output. For example, if a prediction of 0.80 was made, this would round to 1 (Romney)...  For Neural Networks, you should map Obama to 0 and Romney to 1."

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about Piazza intitially and posted here first. Thanks anyways :)